# What role is <T> playing in this definition of ShoppingBasket class?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

Am I correct in understanding that `<T>` refers to just general types of data that can go in the class ShoppingBasket?

```
public class ShoppingBasket<T> implements allBags<T>
```

If I want to define a shoppingBasket class that implements a general interface called allBags and within that shoppingBasket, I want there to be an array of fruits identifiable by an int ID (I made a Fruit class with an int data field containing it's ID with relevant methods) how would I do so without using generics?

Would I just go with

```
public class ShoppingBasket implements allBags{
private Fruit[] fruitBasket;
```

and so on with constructors/getters/setters? I'm not trying to work with an arrayList just an array with a limited capacity since we haven't really learned about dynamic arrays in Java yet. How would the two approaches impact the code I write, particularly with respect to my constructor(s)?

Comment: What methods does `allBags` have in it? Usually, if an interface is generic, some of its methods will refer to `T` in some form or fashion.

Comment: yes it does have methods referring to T and most of them refer to just common operations on a bag like checkFull, checkEmpty, empty, add etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `<T>` is a type parameter and `ShoppingBasket<T>` declares a generic type. If you don't want `ShoppingBasket` to be generic, you can declare it like this:

```
public class ShoppingBasket implements allBags<Fruit> {
    ...
}
```

The constructors and accessors would be declared and implemented as with any non-generic class. You will have to define all the methods declared in the `allBags` interface, using `Fruit` wherever the interface uses `T`. So, for instance, if `allBags` was declared like this:

```
public interface allBags<T> {
    ...
    void addItem(T item);
}
```

you would have to implement your `ShoppingBasket` class to have a method

```
@Override
public void addItem(Fruit item) { ... }
```

(You could choose to rename the argument from `item` to something else, but the rest of the signature would have to be as shown.)